# C#- Outlook Addin - Prevent message suppression

Tags: winforms, outlook-addin

I am currently working on a small addin for Outlook (2007 & 2010).

When I click on a mail item, (not opening it, just to see it in the explorer), a form with a textBox appears. So, i type my text in the box, and then I see that I've made a mistake in my message. Let's say I wrote "Outllook"

So I place my cursor behind the 'l', press 'Del', and.. the message is deleted. Obviously, the mail item is still selected, so when you press the Del key, it acts like it should act.

Link to the screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQar9.png, you can see on the left side that the mail is selected.

So is there anyway I can prevent this from happening? It is really annoying and I can't find a solution. Help will be greatly appreciated!

I hope I made myself clear enough, and I apology for any grammatical mistake I may have made, as English is not my native language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to set the TextBox focus explicitly?

Comment: Yes I did, I should have mentioned that sorry. But as the mail item was still selected, it was deleted as soon as I pressed down the key.

Comment: Look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/vsto/thread/965f0df3-39ce-4822-991a-eea19b047e66 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/df8f47de-0dcb-4485-a0f5-4340447ccc67 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/66b4c342-f8eb-44a7-928c-3db722b3db6f/